# Prevent while, inserting or importing, being duplicate records using textboxs (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, database

I'm doing a program which is importing an excel file to a database and that part works fine. But now I'm working to avoid/prevent the user from inserting or importing duplicate records. I tried to do the composite KEY in all columns but that didn't work. I get the expection :"DBNull"... I think it exists another way by coding?

Here's my code:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/NewFolder/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

            string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/NewFolder/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

            String strConnection = @"Data Source=Ricky-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ImportHere;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=******";
            string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;\"";


            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            excelConnection.Open();
            DataTable schema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string sheetName = schema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from ["+sheetName+"]", excelConnection);
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
            {
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Data";
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(0,0);
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(1,1);
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(2,2);
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(3,3);

                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            }

            excelConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Doing this in the database is the right way. You should work on fixing the database schema instead of trying to find a "workaround" in your code. Also faulty input data could cause the import issues.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I have to do it on code I guess... not in query

Comment: For those that [have the rep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062858/trying-to-avoid-duplicate-records-while-importing-and-insertingnot),

Comment: @Larnu Didn't understand,

Comment: Is the composite unique key failing because there are multiple null values? If so, you could write a CHECK CONSTRAINT: https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_check.asp

Comment: what exactly is the full exception message, and on which line is it happening? And please show the schema of the destination table, then we can understand what the declared keys are. And then show us some sample data of a row which is failing to insert. Then we'll have a much clearer idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a load to a staging table and then do a merge to your final table using a stored proc. The merge will allow you do update existing records and insert new records. This will not insert duplicates. If there is no need for updates then doing an insert from staging to the final table would work too as you can filter out the records that do match and only insert ones that don't match existing records.